# Combine three queries into one single query

Tags: sql, join

I have three interrelated tables:

- Table A contains Name,Age,Marks i want to display in result.
- Table B contains Grade corresponding to Marks.
- Table C contains Parents Name corresponding to Table A.

Now what i want is when I search for a students Name in Table A, I need a output which contains Table A details,Grade from Table B and parent details from Table C. I am able to get results combing two tables.But i am unable to combine three tables.

Comment: Hi, Vibin Jacob. Can you update your question to show what you've got so far with combining two of the tables?

Comment: @D.Schreier Your edit is not helpful & shouldn't have been approved, there is no need to put names of variables etc from code into code format when used in exposition. It's just a choice that could go either way. It adds nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table structure is like this.

```
Table a

| id | name | age | marks|

Table b
| id | marks | grade | 

Table c

| id| tableA_id | parent|
```

Then your query should be

```
SELECT a.name, a.age, a.marks, b.grade, c.parent FROM a INNER JOIN b ON b.marks = a.marks INNER JOIN c ON c.tableA_id = a.id WHERE a.name LIKE "%somename%"
```

Comment: Table b assumptions is wrong it has just grade from range not id reference, say Grade a marks ragen(80-100) b (60-79) c (40-59) something like this